# How do I write a mysql program in Notepad, and can I run it using Windows Command Prompt? If yes, please tell me how it is done

Tags: mysql

I tried to write a mysql program in Notepad. I don't know if I must include any header files to it. Also I don't know how it is executed using windows command prompt (if at all it is possible).

Comment: Have a read of this - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql.html

Answer (score 2):

You can follow below Steps for executing .sql file in MySql

**Step-1** Open mysql in terminal

**Step-2** Run your .sql file by using below sytanx

```
Mysql>source /home/user/Desktop/test.sql
```

Comment: @Anagha if your problem was solved then don't say thanks ..  jut accept  my answer..